# Rounding algorithm based on milliseconds in a week

Tags: javascript, algorithm, flot

I'm trying to figure out the best way to solve rounding a number.

Basically I have this number: var weekMilliseconds = 604800000 (Number of milliseconds in a week)

I have another function that spits out a random number.

What I would like to do is based on the random number, I'd like to output the next multiple of  weekMilliseconds.

For example:

if random # is 1: round up to 604800000

if random # is 604800001 round up to 1209600000 (604800000 * 2)

and so on.....

What is the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Math.ceil()` (which gives you the next whole number up):

```
Math.ceil(randomNumber / weekMilliseconds) * weekMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

You can really do this a few ways. I'd suggest using javascript's [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) function. The idea is, if you want to round to the nearest number `y`, take the input `x` and divide it by `y`. Then round it up to the nearest full number and multiply that by the number you want to round to. So if you had 11 and wanted to round that to 12, divide `11/12` which is `~.917`, round that up, `1`, and multiply `1*12` = 12. So: `roundTo * ceil(random/roundTo)`

```
weekMilliseconds * Math.ceil(number / weekMilliseconds);
```

Take the following:

1. 228, ceil to multiple of 49.

   - `49 * ceil(228/49) = 245`
2. 32, ceil to multiple of 8.

   - `8 * ceil(32/8) = 32`
3. 64, ceil to multiple of 100.

   - `100 * ceil(64/100) = 100`

Comment: I believe you want `ceil` and not `round`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't realize at the time.

Comment: -1 because the description still mentions Math.round() and rounding up and down

Comment: @devnull69 fixed and provided mathematical examples